# Flask-Admin page not found on production

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-admin, vercel

I have built a Flask app and deployed it to production using Vercel (formerly ZEIT). Everything works except the Flask administration.

It returns URL Not Found when accessing `example.com/admin`. Some have suggested to move the `admin.Admin()` initialization block away from the main function. But I don't know what that means. Can somebody help me?

Everything works perfect on my local machine.

Comment: any progress with this deployment? I'm trying to redeploy a Flask app and it seems like Vercel has changed things and my app doesn't work remotely anymore - did you find a decent tutorial on deploying Python flask apps to Vercel to get you started?

Comment: please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

I fixed it by defining admin interface outside `if name == '__main__'` .

This caused the error:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     admin = Admin(application, 'AnyGeeks: Dashboard',index_view=MyIndexView())
     # Add views
     admin.add_view(UserView(Users))
     admin.add_view(ModelView(Tag))
     admin.add_view(PostView(Blog_posts))
     admin.add_view(PostView(Comments))                                                                             
     application.run(debug=True)
```

This what I did to fix it:

```
admin = Admin(application, 'AnyGeeks: Dashboard',index_view=MyIndexView())
# Add views
admin.add_view(UserView(Users))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Tag))
admin.add_view(PostView(Blog_posts))
admin.add_view(PostView(Comments))


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                    

   application.run(debug=True)
```

Now it works perfectly. I have a full website made on flask running on vercel without any issues.

Comment: nice solution! Yes I was reading about the WSGI setup where they recommend putting the python app in a folder but for me my app started to work again after I discovered a bug on one of my blueprint routes which didn't appear locally - I found it by switching the preferred build @now/python to @ardnt/now-python-wsgi I could get better logging and see my error in the longer stack trace - then I switched back once I fixed it and it worked again!